# Paged collection view edititem in silverlight 4 application

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, pagedcollectionview

How to use EditItem method for pagedcollectionview in silverlight 4 application..??

Comment: You should use ObsrvableCollection Instad Of List

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the solution here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/e7e40e1b-3bcb-450e-817b-d5def0d7ddd2/